# UICollectionViewCell only showing when a certain criteria is met

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I do not know if this is possible but, I am trying to return a cell using CollectionView cellForItem only if a certain criteria is met.

Here is my function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FriendsRecentCell", for: indexPath) as! FriendsRecentCell

        var fObj = PFObject(className: FRIENDS_CLASS_NAME)
        fObj = recentArray[indexPath.row]

        // Get User Pointer
        let userPointer = fObj[FRIENDS_IS_FRIEND_WITH] as! PFUser
        userPointer.fetchIfNeededInBackground(block: { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {

                // Get heys sent to you as currentUser
                let query = PFQuery(className: HEYS_CLASS_NAME)
                query.whereKey(HEYS_RECEIVER, equalTo: PFUser.current()!)
                query.whereKey(HEYS_SENDER, equalTo: userPointer)
                query.countObjectsInBackground { (count, error) in
                    if count != 0 {
                        // Get User fullname
                        cell.userLabelRecent.text = "\(userPointer[USER_FULLNAME]!)"

                        // Get Avatar
                        cell.avatarImageRecent.image = UIImage(named: "avatar")
                        cell.avatarImageRecent.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatarImageRecent.bounds.size.width/2
                        let imageFile = userPointer[USER_AVATAR] as? PFFile
                        imageFile?.getDataInBackground(block: { (imageData, error) in
                            if error == nil {
                                if let imageData = imageData {
                                    cell.avatarImageRecent.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                                }}})
                    } else {
                    }}

            }})

        return cell

    }
```

I only want the cell to return `if count != 0`. Is there any way to go about doing this? I am completely lost.

Comment: I suggest you preprocess all of this data, put it in an array and then load your collectionView. Can provide a little more guidance tomorrow if you're interested.

Comment: Yes I would love some help tomorrow @toddg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point at which this method is called, you've already told the collection view that there's a cell that exists at that index path.  Now that you've done so, you *have* to supply a cell; there's no way not to – the method signature is non-optional.

If you only want a cell to appear under certain circumstances, then you have to handle it earlier in the process.  When `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` is called, you need to determine if the cell should be shown and return the correct number of items.  Then you'll only be asked for those cells.